# Automapper refer to existing subtype mapping in custom member mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

My database entities look as follows (redacted down to relevant information):

```cs
public class Task
{
    public Guid? StatusId { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StatusLastModified { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // several other properties redacted
}
```

Tasks initially have no status (StatusLastModified is then also null), and once the first status has been assigned, tasks will always have a status (and StatusLastModified is then also not null).

For the sake of this question, you can assume that these properties will always both be null or not-null, I don't need to account for anomalies where one is null and the other isn't.

For my DTOs, I want to map this to the following structure:

```cs
public struct TaskDto
{
    public TaskStatusDto? Status { get; set; }
}

public struct TaskStatusDto
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; } // maps from Task.StatusLastModified 
    public StatusDto Status { get; set; } // maps from Task.Status
}

public struct StatusDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // and all the other properties from the Status entity
}
```

The goal here is that my `TaskDto` only has an underlying `TaskStatusDto` when there is an actual status, and otherwise it should be null. This is helpful as it negates the need to constantly null check *both* the status object and the last modified date.

However, I am struggling to configure this mapping in Automapper. I have created the mapping between `Status` and `StatusDto`:

```cs
configuration
     .CreateMap<Status, StatusDto>();
```

My real mapping is more complicated but it's also proven to work so you can assume that this is a valid and working mapping.

The problem I'm faced with is how I can refer to this mapping when creating the custom mapping between `Task` and `TaskDto`. I've currently tried the following:

```cs
configuration
    .CreateMap<Task, TaskDto>()
    .ForMember(
            dto => dto.Status,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(entity => 
                entity.Status == null
                    ? null as TaskStatusDto?
                    : new TaskStatusDto()
                    {
                        TimeStamp = entity.StatusLastModified.Value,
                        Status = // ??? make me a StatusDto from entity.Status
                    }
        ));
```

The part I don't know how to fill in is the comment. I have access to the original entity (`entity.Status`), but I don't know how to tell Automapper to convert this object to a `StatusDto` according to a mapping that it should already know.

My approach also feels more contrived than it should be, but I don't know how to otherwise introduce this intermediary `TaskStatusDto` object if it isn't backed by an actual entity in my source data.

---

A small footnote, unsure if relevant: I am using [Heroic.Automapper](https://github.com/MattHoneycutt/HeroicFramework/tree/master/Heroic.AutoMapper), which means that the `TaskDto` and `StatusDto` maps are being configured in separate locations (i.e. inside the `TaskDto` and `StatusDto` class, respectively) and the Heroic framework will combine all these maps at runtime.

```cs
public class TaskDto : IMapFrom<Task>, IHaveCustomMappings
{
     public void CreateMappings(IMapperConfigurationExpression configuration)
     {
         // mapping from Task to TaskDto
     }
}

public class StatusDto : IMapFrom<Status>, IHaveCustomMappings
{
     public void CreateMappings(IMapperConfigurationExpression configuration)
     {
         // mapping from Status to StatusDto
     }
}
```

However, as far as I understand it, the setting up of the map itself isn't Heroic-specific and should be purely Automapper syntax.

Comment: Research `context.Mapper`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu: What precisely is the `context` you're referring to?

Comment: Nevermind :) Just create a map from `Status` to `TaskStatusDto?` and remove the `MapFrom`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu: How would I then access `Task.StatusLastModified`, since that is the source data for `TaskStatusDto.Timestamp`?

Comment: You can pass it in `context.Items`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu: Back to my original question: What precisely is the `context` you're referring to?  An actual answer with explanation would be nice, rather than playing 20 questions in the comment section. I suspect you know the solution and deserve the points for it, but (unintentionally) dripfeeding it really isn't effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a cleaner solution would be to create your own [CustomResolver](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html):

```
public class TaskStatusDtoResolver : IValueResolver<Task, TaskDto, TaskStatusDto?>
{
    public TaskStatusDto? Resolve(Task source, TaskDto destination, TaskStatusDto? member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source.Status == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new TaskStatusDto
        {
            Status = context.Mapper.Map<StatusDto>(source.Status),
            Timestamp = source.StatusLastModified.Value
        };
    }
}
```

And you can use the following configuration:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Status, StatusDto>();
cfg.CreateMap<Task, TaskDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom<TaskStatusDtoResolver>());
```

[See the working example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3qgUYG)

---

Alternatively you can define all the mappings in the configuration:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Status, StatusDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Task, TaskDto>().ForMember(
         dest => dest.Status,
         src => src.MapFrom((task, taskDto, member, context) =>
         {
             return task.Status == null ? null as TaskStatusDto? : new TaskStatusDto()
             {
                 Timestamp = task.StatusLastModified.Value,
                 Status = context.Mapper.Map<StatusDto>(task.Status)
             };
         }
     ));
});
```

Comment: That last snippet is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks for the help! :) (bounty coming your way when I can assign it)

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.